# img floating to left of the text

Tags: html, css, css-float

I cannot make the image floating to left of the text. Could you please help? And also can I write width="200" height="200" in CSS? If it is possible, how? Thanks for any help.

```
Html code

        <div class="content">
        <img src="img1.jpg" class="bw" width="200" height="200" alt="king">
        Content is very important bla bla bla....Content is very important bla bla bla....Content is very important bla bla bla....Content is very important bla bla bla....Content is very important bla bla bla....Content is very important bla bla bla....Content is very important bla bla bla....Content is very important bla bla bla....Content is very important bla bla bla....Content is very important bla bla bla....
        </div>


CSS
     div.content {
         width:80%;
         padding-top: 2pc;
         padding-left: 5pc;
         text-align:left;
         font: 10pt Helvetica,"Helvetica neue", Arial, sans-serif;
         margin-left: 100px;
         margin-right: 300px;
         color: #000000 }

     div.img.bw {
         float:left;
         margin:4px; }
```

Comment: CSS: width:200px; height:200px;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div.img.bw` is incorrect. You should define that as `div img.bw`. You need to target and element that is an `image` with the class `bw` inside an element that is a `div`. Which is what the `div img.bw` targets. Also to define the height and width use:

```
 div img.bw {
  float:left;
  margin:4px; 
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The big issue is that your selector is wrong on your image.

It should be:

```
div img.bw {
float: left;
margin: 4px; 
}
```

Right now css is looking for a div with the class "img".